# How to make google chart same size with its container

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, business-objects-sdk

I'm trying to develop custom donut component for SAP BusinessObjects Design Studio by using google donut chart. It's like DOM(Document Object Model).

I want to make donut chart responsive because of the compatibility with the other components. To do this, in classic DOM I used bootstrap "col-md-6" div as a container:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2000', 1000, 400],
    ['2001', 1170, 460],
    ['2002', 660, 1120],
    ['2003', 1030, 540],
    ['2004', 1000, 400],
    ['2005', 1170, 460],
    ['2006', 660, 1120],
    ['2007', 1030, 540],
    ['2008', 1000, 400],
    ['2009', 1170, 460],
    ['2010', 660, 1120],
    ['2011', 1030, 540]
  ]);
  var options = {
    backgroundColor: {
      fill: 'none'
    },
    pieHole: 0.4,
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
      color: 'white',
    },
    title: 'Company Performance',
    chartArea: {
      top: 20,
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%"
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'labeled',
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        color: '#000'
      }
    },
    titlePosition: 'out',
    titleTextStyle: {
      color: '#000',
      bold: true,
      italic: true,
      fontSize: 16,
      position: 'centered'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);

function drawChart2() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2000', 1000, 400],
    ['2001', 1170, 460],
    ['2002', 660, 1120],
    ['2003', 1030, 540],
    ['2004', 1000, 400],
    ['2005', 1170, 460],
    ['2006', 660, 1120],
    ['2007', 1030, 540],
    ['2008', 1000, 400],
    ['2009', 1170, 460],
    ['2010', 660, 1120],
    ['2011', 1030, 540]
  ]);
  var options = {
    backgroundColor: {
      fill: 'none'
    },
    pieHole: 0.4,
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
      color: 'white',
    },
    title: 'Company Performance',
    chartArea: {
      top: 20,
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%"
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'labeled',
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        color: '#000'
      }
    },
    titlePosition: 'out',
    titleTextStyle: {
      color: '#000',
      bold: true,
      italic: true,
      fontSize: 16,
      position: 'centered'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv2'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}


$(window).resize(function() {
  drawChart();
  drawChart2();
});
```

```css
.chart {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="chartDiv" class="chart"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="chartDiv2" class="chart"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But in design studio, we need to use this component in the Grid Layout Cell. Because of this wrapping new divs, my design is broke down in design studio side. Another divs u see in the picture, comes from design studio sdk developer mode. But I can access them with js. Just know which div to edit.
Both two photos of my div hierarchy of html design and component design:

[normal dom design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvUlj.png)

[design studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7GB7.png)

Here is the snippet I'm working with design studio, but you can't run it. me.init() method works like main method.

```js
sap.designstudio.sdk.Component.subclass("com.try.donut.Donut", function() {

 var me = this;
 var myDiv;
 me._width;
 me._height;

 me.drawChart = function() {
  //me.$().width();
  
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [ 'Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses' ], [ '2000', 1000, 400 ],
    [ '2001', 1170, 460 ], [ '2002', 660, 1120 ],
    [ '2003', 1030, 540 ], [ '2004', 1000, 400 ],
    [ '2005', 1170, 460 ] ]);
  var options = {
   backgroundColor : {
    fill : 'none'
   },
   pieHole : 0.4,
   pieSliceTextStyle : {
    color : 'white',
   },
   title : 'Company Performance',
   chartArea : {
    top: "30",
    bottom: "30",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%"
   },
   legend : {
    position : 'labeled',
    textStyle : {
     color : '#000'
    }
   },
   titlePosition : 'out',
   titleTextStyle : {
    color : '#000',
    bold : true,
    italic : true,
    fontSize : 16,
    position : 'centered'
   }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(myDiv.id+'_chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
 };

 me.redraw = function() {
  myDiv = this.$()[0];
  
  var componentDiv = d3.select(myDiv);
  componentDiv.selectAll("*").remove();
  
  var wrapperDiv = componentDiv.append("div").attr("class","col-md-6");
  wrapperDiv.append("div").attr("class","chart").attr("id",myDiv.id+"_chart_div");
  
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){ 
      me.drawChart(); 
     });
 };
 $(window).resize(function(){
    me.redraw();
 });
 me.init = function() {
  me.redraw();
 };

 // /////***** SET - GET *****\\\\\\
 me.height = function(value) {
  if (value === undefined) {
   return me._height;
  } else {
   me._height = value;
   return me;
  }
 };

 me.width = function(value) {
  if (value === undefined) {
   return me._width;
  } else {
   me._width = value;
   return me;
  }
 };
});
```

what should i do to new div's attribute to fix this problem?

Comment: can you share the working snippet you are trying?

Comment: @SahilDhir I edited but you can't see this running till u connect eclipse to design studio, it has mechanism to create sdk, different div's comes from this mechanism also.

Comment: I understand. You have to change the width of the elements coming from that mechanism.

Comment: @SahilDhir so which div should i change width to 100%? Can't change the table cell width, but with something I can fit my component to container cell.